# Javascript - Medium level - Make external button in document do the same as submit button in form

Tags: javascript

I would like an external button to trigger the same function beneath, onclick. Anybody knows how I do that?

Function is inside a variable

var mTid = { ....
                  init: function() {    .....
                                        .....

```
    mTid.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {     //This is the function I would like to invoke from a button outside the form

        }, true);
```

// [v] is just instead of .value

Comment: What do you mean by "external button"?

Comment: It's just a button outside the form. In regular html document.getElementById('ID_of_button')

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to access an anonymous function from outside. While there may be a way to do this is JavaScript, I don't suggest it. Instead, consider pulling the anonymous function out and instead making it a stand alone function you can pass to addEventListener(). You would end up with code such as this:

```
function example(event) {
    ...
}

mTid.$form.addEventListener("submit", example);
```

It's generally a best-practice to use anonymous functions only when the function will be used in one case and one case only. By pulling the function out, you can then use it in many different ways such as passing it as an action for an external button.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I will look at separating it, but it's part of a bigger script (ofcourse) and I believe this is the only function I want to do this with, maybe one more later on ( it's for the mobile interface). So if anybody knows a quick fix for using the same, please let me know :) Thanks non the less :)